# Change the default currency of site after deploying to host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, currency, culture, regional-settings, web-publishing

I have developed a simple website with MVC 5 .NET 4.5.1
There are some decimal values that I show them as a formatted string like this:

```
    <p>
      @Value.ToString("C0");
    </p>
```

As my PC regional settings sets to Persian-Farsi, this works fine on my PC when I run it and shows me the results as below (example value):

```
    R 123,456,000
```

After publishing the website to my host (provided by http://somee.com), the results changes to this:

```
    $ 123,456,000
```

I know the culture of host web server is en-US and I want to change it.

Is there a way to change my `web.config` file to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Add this to the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="fa" culture="fa-IR" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This should set culture to Persian for the whole app

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that give me the big idea. actually I set the **enableClientBasedCulture="true"** attribute plus your mentioned one. now that is worked correctly. thank you @Andrei